# how to put specific number of characters in front of a string in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar, zero-padding

I want to fix a string to length of 20 characters after the operation. For example, if my string is `1455` then new string should be `00000000000000001455` (20 characters) with 16 `0`s in front. Or if my string is `12345678` then new string should be `00000000000012345678` (20 chars) with 12 `0`s in front.

I can do it in a user-defined function but I wonder if there is an easy way to do it in Oracle? I googled but couldn't find any similar solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this:

```
select lpad('1455',20,'0') from dual;
```

Comment: that's what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LPAD()`:

```
SELECT LPAD('1455', 20, '0') FROM dual;
```

or generally:

```
SELECT LPAD(mystring, 20, '0') FROM mytable;
```

If the length of `mystring` is greater than 20 characters it will be truncated to 20 characters (and not padded!).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('1455', 'fm00000000000000000000') FROM dual;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d830ad2a6244837c01ee64eed4e482a)**

Comment: This will implicitly convert your value to NUMBER and then back to CHAR. So it will fail if your string is not a valid number.